# Type `Class Name` does not provide a call operator. C++

Tags: c++, constructor

Assume the following:

- We have `class Person`, and `class Job`.

  ```
  class Job {
  public: 
      Job(); //default constructor
      Job(char * n); //parameterized constructor
      ~Job(); //destructor
  protected:
      Salary p; //another class
  }    

  class Person {
  public:
       Person(); //default constructor
       ~Person(); //destructor
       void set_job_name(char * n); //pass the job name to `Job` constructor

  protected:
       Job obj;
  };
  ```

When I try to use `set_job_name(char * n)` to call the parameterized constructor for class Job, I get this error `Type "Job" does not provide a call operator.` Any ideas?

This is what `set_job_name()` do:

```
void Person::set_job_name(char * n) {
    obj(n);
}
```

Comment: In this case `obj(n)` is not a call to the `Job(char* n)` constructor. It is a call to `Job::operator()(char* n)` (which does not exist). You might want to take a brief C++ refresher: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: The very name `Person::set_job_name` smells fishy. Why not `Person::set_job`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
obj(n)
```

is equivalent to:

```
obj.operator()(n)
```

That is not right since `Job` which does not have an `operator()` function.

To reset the value of `obj`, use:

```
void Person::set_job_name(char * n) 
{
   obj = Job(n);
}
```

You can simplify it a bit by providing a `set_name` function in `Job`. If you do that, the above can be:

```
void Person::set_job_name(char * n) 
{
   obj.set_name(n);
}
```

Comment: I did that `obj = Job(n);` but I get a seg-fault in the destructor of another class inside `Job`! I didn't add that class in my question, I will add it now

Comment: @Prall1988, you should take at [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). That will be helpful if you allocate memory in the constructor and deallocate memory in the destructor.